# What's the correct way to add workspace dev-dependencies in Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In my virtual manifest `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[workspace.dev-dependencies]
serial_test = "2.0.0"
```

In a non-virtual manifest `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dev-dependencies]
serial_test.workspace = true
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Caused by:
  error inheriting `serial_test` from workspace root manifest's `workspace.dependencies.serial_test`

Caused by:
  `dependency.serial_test` was not found in `workspace.dependencies`
```

This works for the `dependencies` section. How should workspace dependencies be specified for `dev-dependencies`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare it like any other dependency in the workspace, like this:

```ini
[workspace.dependencies]
serial_test = "2.0.0"
```

```ini
[dev-dependencies]
serial_test.workspace = true
```

Whether a dependency is a dev-dependency or not only applies to the individual package; both `[dependencies]` and `[dev-dependencies]` can use data from `[workspace.dependencies]`.

Comment: When you put it that way, it makes total sense and the error message becomes self-explanatory.